# Code to do an Image Preview for my asp.net website

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am trying to do an image preview function on my asp.net website. 
The way that i would expect it to work is when the user uploads an image through the fileupload function, a preview would be shown next to it.

My current javascript code looks like this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function imagepreview(input)
    {
        if(input.files && input.files[0])
        {
            var fildr = new FileReader();
            fildr.onload = function(e)
            {
                $('#imgprw').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            fildr.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
</script>
```

The fileupload control code in the .aspx file...

```
<div>
        <center><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Profile Picture :"></asp:Label></center>
        </br>
    <center>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" onchange="imagepreview(this)"></asp:FileUpload>
    </center>
        <center>
            <asp:Image ID="imgprw" runat="server" AlternateText="Image Preview..."></asp:Image>
        </center>
        <center>
            <asp:Label ID="lblPhotoUploadStatus" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        </center>
    </div>
```

Had got this code online, but it does not work with my asp.net website.

When i try to upload in an image through the fileupload control in my asp.net website, the image preview does not appear.

Hopefully somebody is able to help me with this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: Is jQuery defined? Have you tried `document.getElementById("imgprw").src = e.target.result;`?

Comment: Heyy guest271314, how do i go about implementing that into my current code? :)

Comment: Is input in imagepreview function populated with the correct element?

Comment: I am not too sure about that Vijay... :(